# How to read zipfile from bytes in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm reading gzip file from bytes, which I have loaded from AWS S3, now I have tried below code to read:

```
gzip_bytes = s3.get_file()  # for example I have loaded S3
gzip_file = BytesIO(gzip_bytes)

with GzipFile(gzip_file, mode="rb") as file:
     # Todo somthing
```

I'm getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    with GzipFile(BytesIO(pre_file_bytes), mode="rb") as pre_zip_file:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 163, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
```

How can I resolve that issue? Or maybe I'm missing something

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gzipfile contructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) takes:

```
class gzip.GzipFile(filename=None, mode=None, compresslevel=9, fileobj=None, mtime=None)
```

However, you are passing Bytes instead of a string as the `filename`.

This is explained by the error message:

> expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO

It looks like you should download the file, then provide the filename to the downloaded file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I have used the `fileobj` parameter and its not throwing error, but in the gzip file I have single CSV which I want to read in `csv.reader`, you have any idea?

Comment: I have resolve my issue by using `GzipFile` class `read` function, Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

To decompress and read a downloaded `gzip` file, perhaps from a URL, pass the corresponding `io.BytesIO` object to the `fileobj` parameter instead of the default `filename` parameter.  For example,

```py
from io import BytesIO
from gzip import GzipFile
import urllib.request
    
url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://oeis.org/names.gz")

with GzipFile(fileobj=BytesIO(url.read()), mode='rb') as f:
    # now you may treat f as an uncompressed file
    # for example, print first line of file
    for l in f:
      print(l) 
      break
```

(This was already pointed out by the OP in a comment.  I'm putting it in an answer so it is easier to find.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I have already mentioned in the comment I have used the same approach to solve this.